# Lag Calculations using SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to perform some calculations using sql (big query).
I attach a reference of my table output.
What I would like to perform is an additional column that will be calculated as follows:

- First row of new column: row two of "conteggio" column / row one of "conteggio" column
- Second row of new column: row three of "conteggio" column / row one of "conteggio" column
- Third row of new column: row four of "conteggio" column / row one of "conteggio" column

and so on...

What I thought was to use the lag() function, but my aim is to have an offset indicator that changes and that first row must be fixed in the calculation.
Do you have any ideas on how to use sql formulas or how to write in a smart way a query to have this kind of result?
It is not necessary to have queries in bigquery, even in other languages, then I will try to convert with bigquery tools.

Thanks a lot

```
+-----+---------+-----------+---------+------------------------+-----------------+
| Row | stageid | conteggio | country |       Deal_Stage       | Conversion_Rate |
+-----+---------+-----------+---------+------------------------+-----------------+
|   1 |       1 |       494 | All     | 1. Prospecting         | null            |
|   2 |       2 |       493 | All     | 2. Meeting Preparation | 0.998           |
|   3 |       3 |       338 | All     | 3. 1st Meeting         | 0.6856          |
|   4 |       4 |       164 | All     | 4. Demo Meeting        | 0.4852          |
|   5 |       5 |        62 | All     | 5. Proposal            | 0.378           |
|   6 |       6 |        62 | All     | 6. Proposal Sent       | 1               |
|   7 |       7 |        37 | All     | 7. Closed Won          | 0.5968          |
|   8 |       1 |       373 | Brazil  | 1. Prospecting         | null            |
|   9 |       2 |       354 | Brazil  | 2. Meeting Preparation | 0.9491          |
|  10 |       3 |       238 | Brazil  | 3. 1st Meeting         | 0.6723          |
|  11 |       4 |       102 | Brazil  | 4. Demo Meeting        | 0.4286          |
|  12 |       5 |        27 | Brazil  | 5. Proposal            | 0.2647          |
|  13 |       6 |        27 | Brazil  | 6. Proposal Sent       | 1               |
|  14 |       7 |        17 | Brazil  | 7. Closed Won          | 0.6296          |
|  15 |       1 |         5 | Chile   | 1. Prospecting         | 0.2941          |
|  16 |       2 |         1 | Chile   | 2. Meeting Preparation | 0.2             |
|  17 |       3 |         1 | Chile   | 3. 1st Meeting         | 1               |
|  18 |       4 |         1 | Chile   | 4. Demo Meeting        | 1               |
|  19 |       5 |         1 | Chile   | 5. Proposal            | 1               |
|  20 |       6 |         1 | Chile   | 6. Proposal Sent       | 1               |
|  21 |       7 |         1 | Chile   | 7. Closed Won          | 1               |
|  22 |       1 |        37 | Italy   | 1. Prospecting         | 37              |
|  23 |       2 |        33 | Italy   | 2. Meeting Preparation | 0.8919          |
|  24 |       3 |        32 | Italy   | 3. 1st Meeting         | 0.9697          |
|  25 |       4 |        28 | Italy   | 4. Demo Meeting        | 0.875           |
|  26 |       5 |        19 | Italy   | 5. Proposal            | 0.6786          |
|  27 |       6 |        19 | Italy   | 6. Proposal Sent       | 1               |
|  28 |       7 |        10 | Italy   | 7. Closed Won          | 0.5263          |
|  29 |       1 |        51 | Mexico  | 1. Prospecting         | 5.1             |
|  30 |       2 |        42 | Mexico  | 2. Meeting Preparation | 0.8235          |
|  31 |       3 |        23 | Mexico  | 3. 1st Meeting         | 0.5476          |
|  32 |       4 |         9 | Mexico  | 4. Demo Meeting        | 0.3913          |
|  33 |       5 |         3 | Mexico  | 5. Proposal            | 0.3333          |
|  34 |       6 |         3 | Mexico  | 6. Proposal Sent       | 1               |
|  35 |       7 |         1 | Mexico  | 7. Closed Won          | 0.3333          |
|  36 |       1 |        28 | Spain   | 1. Prospecting         | 28              |
|  37 |       2 |        63 | Spain   | 2. Meeting Preparation | 2.25            |
|  38 |       3 |        44 | Spain   | 3. 1st Meeting         | 0.6984          |
|  39 |       4 |        24 | Spain   | 4. Demo Meeting        | 0.5455          |
|  40 |       5 |        12 | Spain   | 5. Proposal            | 0.5             |
|  41 |       6 |        12 | Spain   | 6. Proposal Sent       | 1               |
|  42 |       7 |         8 | Spain   | 7. Closed Won          | 0.6667          |
+-----+---------+-----------+---------+------------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: With this data how do you determine "first" or "Second" or "third". What columns determined order? Also is your data partitioned/windowed? Is it "First" for all records, or just "First" for each country? Lastly, please copy/paste your text and table data as text here in Stackoverflow. No one wants to have to transcribe text tabular data from a picture to replicate and build sql. You can use SO markdown or site like https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to wrangle your table data.

Comment: thanks for your inputs and your help with showing data.
The order I am following is the one present in "deal_stage" column and the calculation will have to be repetead from first step whenever the column "Country" changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  round(lead(conteggio) over win / first_value(conteggio) over win, 4) as new_col
from your_table 
window win as (partition by country order by stageid)
-- order by country, stageid
```

if applied to sample data in  your question - output is

[image]